# RCP run my view part instead of the default view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Iam New to the RCP and I had run the RCP application with a view
and I have created a new view with my needs.
The problem is when I used to run the program it runs the default view,What shall I do to run my view???

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a perspective and set it as default?